# Count the number of rows that come after each row by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
group bin
a 0
a 0
a 0
a 1 
a 1
b 0 
b 1
b 1
```

For each group and for each row I want to count of rows the number of rows that come after each row and I also want to take the sum of bin of rows that come after each row.  So the output I'm looking for is this:

```
group bin countafter sum
a     0   4          2
a     0   3          2
a     0   2          2 
a     1   1          1
a     1   0          0

b     0   2          2
b     1   1          1
b     1   0          0
```

In this case, the sum in group a sums the bin for all rows that come after each row.  For example, in row 4 of group a, there is only one row after where the bin = 1, so sum is 1.

Doing a group by and then doing either an apply(lambda x:) or filter only work on the group.  How do I apply a count and sum function for each row in the group?

Comment: What are you summing?

Comment: can you explain the logic behind sum?

Comment: Apologies, I realize that was confusing. I edited the post with a little more detail.  I'm summing the bin column.  So for row 3 of group a, it would be Sum(bin[4], bin[5])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC first using `cumcount`, then for the sum using `cumsum` and `sum` get the different

```
df['countafter']=df.groupby('group').cumcount(ascending=False)
df['sum']=df.groupby('group').bin.transform('sum')-df.groupby('group').bin.cumsum()
df
Out[7]: 
  group  bin  countafter  sum
0     a    0           4    2
1     a    0           3    2
2     a    0           2    2
3     a    1           1    1
4     a    1           0    0
5     b    0           2    2
6     b    1           1    1
7     b    1           0    0
```